# Python2.7 getting the next tag by using bs4

Tags: html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the part of the html from

http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&r=1&p=1&f=G&l=50&d=PTXT&S1=V2V&OS=V2V&RS=V2V

```
<CENTER><b>U.S. Patent Documents</b></CENTER>
<TABLE width="100%"> 
    <TR>
        <TH scope="col" width="33%"></TH> 
        <TH scope="col" width="33%"></TH>
        <TH scope="col" width="34%"></TH>
    </TR> 
    <TR> 
        <TD align="left"><a href="http://appft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?TERM1=20130322542&Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PG01&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.html&r=0&f=S&l=50" target="_blank">2013/0322542</a></TD>
        <TD align=left>December 2013</TD>
        <TD align=left>Senzaki et al</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD align=left><a href="http://appft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?TERM1=20130336397&Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PG01&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.html&r=0&f=S&l=50" target="_blank">2013/0336397</a></TD>
        <TD align=left>December 2013</TD>
        <TD align=left>Senzaki et al.</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

My question is, I want to extract the TABLE if the "U.S. Patent Documents" exists in the html as shown in the figure (link [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4SBV.jpg)).

However the title('U.S. Patent Documents') and TABLE body are not sharing the same top tag so i couldn't use something like

```
tb_body = soup.find('center').find('table')
```

So is there any way can help me to do that?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily done using `tb_body.findNext('table')`. If it exists, a `table` Tag is returned, else, `None`.

Alternatively, you can use `tb_body.find_next_sibling('table')`.

Both of these commands return the table if it exists:

```
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
  ...
```